# A problem solvable by a first-degree equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

In a two-digit number, the tens digit exceeds the units digit by $3$. The difference between twice the number with the digits reversed and the number itself is $42$. What is the number?

**My solution**: Let be $\boxed{x}\boxed y$ the number with two digits. $\boxed{x}\boxed y=10x+y$. The tens digit exceeds the units digit by $3$. Hence:

$$x=10\cdot (y+3)+y.$$

But $2\boxed{y}\boxed x-\boxed{x}\boxed y=42 \iff 20\cdot (y+3)+2y \ldots $.

I don't know how to set it up from the beginning. How should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the digit of tens $a$ and the digit of units $b$. From the first condition you get $a=b+3$ and from the second $2(10b+a)-(10a+b)=42$. Solving you should get $a=9, b=6$.

Comment: In the meantime, thank you very much. How should one proceed by setting up a first-order equation?

Comment: I guess that: "the tens digit exceeds the units digit by $3$" translates to $b=a+3$ assuming the number is $N=a+10b$

Comment: @NoChance if you want to change the name of the variables...

Answer (score 1):

> In a two-digit number, the tens digit exceeds the units digit by 3 .
> The difference between twice the number with the digits reversed and
> the number itself is 42 . What is the number?

Notice that to solve this you need to use first-degree "system of equations composed of 2 equation in 2 variables" as will be shown below.

$$N=xy=x+10y$$

The tens digit exceeds the units digit by 3
$$y-x=3 \tag 1 $$

The difference between twice the number with the digits reversed and the number itself is $42$

$$2(10x+y)-x-10y=42$$
$$20x+2y-x-10y=42$$
$$19x-8y=42$$
Using (1), substitute the value of y in the last equation to get:
$$19x-8*(3+x)=19x-24-8x=42$$
$$11x=66$$
$$x=6$$

To get the value of $y$ Use (1) with the obtained value of $x=6$:
$$y-6=3$$

$$y=9$$

Now verify the answer:

$N=6+9*10$

$$9-6=3...true$$

$$2*69-96=42...true$$

Comment: The problem is that I have not explained linear systems to my first-year students.

Comment: This problem requires good knowledge of basic Algebra. It would be very confusing for a beginner in my opinion.

Comment: My students are beginners 

Comment: Maybe you can keep the problem but change the numbers so that instead of $19x-8y=42$, you can use an equation where the solution can be guessed by inspection.